# Highcharts: picking points in one chart and have the same points highlight in other charts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have 9 charts that generate in one container each on a page.  What I want to do is use one chart to choose samples and have them highlighted, list them in a table and simultaneously have them show up in the other 8 charts. I have the part where I can get the table to generate, but I can't get the series to show up in the the charts.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>HighCharts Data Output</title> 
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script>

$(function () {
var $report = $('#report'),
    selectedPoints = [];

$('#container1').highcharts({
chart: {
type: 'scatter',
zoomType: 'xy',
plotBorderColor: 'black',
plotBorderWidth: 1,
},
   tooltip: {
   formatter: function() {
   return this.series.name + '<br><b>X: </b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.x, '1',',') +'<b>  Y:</b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, '1',',') +'<br><span style="color: ' + this.series.color + '; font-weight:bold;">' + this.point.samp +'</span>';
},
},
subtitle: {
text: 'Data Analysis'
},
title: {
text: 'DataX vs DataY'
},
xAxis: {
minorGridLineColor: '#F0F0F0',
minorTickInterval: 'auto',
min: 0.05,
max: 900,
title: {
enabled: true,
text: 'XData'
},
 startOnTick: true,
 endOnTick: true,
 showLastLabel: true
 },

yAxis: {
min: 0.05,
max: 900,
title: {
text: 'YData)' 
}
},

plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            point: {
                events: {
                    select: function (event) {
                        var chart = this.series.chart;

                        var selectedPointsStr = "";
                        if (event.accumulate) {
                            selectedPoints.push(this);
                        } else {
                            selectedPoints = [this];
                        }
                        // when is the chart object updated? after this function finshes?
                        $.each(selectedPoints, function (i, value) {
                            selectedPointsStr += "<tr><td>" + value.x  + "</td><td> " + value.y + "</td></tr><br>";
                            //var Plot = eval(selectedPointsStr);
                        });
                        $report.html(selectedPointsStr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

series: [{

type: 'line',
name: '1:1 Line',
data: [[0, 0], [1000, 1000]],
marker: {
enabled: false
},
states: {
hover: {
lineWidth: 0
}
},
enableMouseTracking: false
},

{name: 'group1',
data: [{x:115.9,y:179,samp:'CR13-451D_384.5-386'},{x:37.5,y:188,samp:'CR13-389D_292-293.5'}]
},
{name: 'group2',
data: [{x:27.8,y:64,samp:'CR12-361D_226.5-228'},{x:51.9,y:228,samp:'CR12-369D_428-429.5'}] 
},
{name: 'group3',
data: [{x:27.2,y:863,samp:'CR12-346D_973.5-975'},{x:478.8,y:575,samp:'CR12-348D_1100-1101.5'},{x:39.1,y:598,samp:'CR12-360D_1167.5-1169'}]
},
{name: 'group4',
data: [{x:22.8,y:244,samp:'CR11-149D_333-334.5'},{x:25.3,y:224,samp:'CR11-149D_346.5-348'},{x:34.4,y:128,samp:'CR11-196D_130.5-132'},{x:198.4,y:31,samp:'CR11-197D_271.5-273'},{x:0.9,y:14,samp:'CR11-204D_127.5-129'},{x:9.1,y:223,samp:'CR11-224D_207-208.5'},{x:0.05,y:288,samp:'CR11-224D_64.5-66'},{x:0.05,y:120,samp:'CR11-228D_14-15.5'},{x:5.6,y:181,samp:'CR11-231D_93-94.5'},{x:95.6,y:0.05,samp:'CR11-246D_90-91.5'},{x:0.05,y:176,samp:'CR11-256D_130.5-132'},{x:13.1,y:133,samp:'CR11-258D_321-322.5'},{x:0.05,y:246,samp:'CR11-260D_90-91.5'},{x:340.9,y:185,samp:'CR11-266D_304.5-306'},{x:0.05,y:143,samp:'CR11-267D_12.5-14'},{x:33.1,y:239,samp:'CR11-267D_135.5-137'},{x:0.05,y:213,samp:'CR11-267D_314-315.5'},{x:180.9,y:23,samp:'CR11-270D_396.5-398'},{x:114.4,y:169,samp:'CR11-272D_301.5-303'},{x:235.9,y:12,samp:'CR11-272D_318-319.5'},{x:118.1,y:103,samp:'CR11-272D_361.5-363'},{x:22.8,y:144,samp:'CR11-274D_285-286.5'},{x:48.8,y:109,samp:'CR11-275D_209-210.5'},{x:28.4,y:185,samp:'CR11-275D_231.5-233'},{x:129.1,y:5,samp:'CR11-275D_365-366.5'},{x:18.8,y:234,samp:'CR11-277D_33-34.5'},{x:0.05,y:165,samp:'CR11-280D_145.5-147'},{x:0.05,y:261,samp:'CR11-280D_15-16.5'},{x:24.1,y:174,samp:'CR11-280D_337.5-339'},{x:15.6,y:66,samp:'CR11-280D_420-421.5'},{x:0.05,y:174,samp:'CR11-284D_217.5-219'},{x:12.2,y:441,samp:'CR11-289D_39.5-41'},{x:107.8,y:240,samp:'CR11-291D_279.5-281'},{x:0.05,y:143,samp:'CR11-297D_118.5-120'},{x:23.8,y:160,samp:'CR11-301D_127.5-129'},{x:0.05,y:321,samp:'CR11-302D_313.5-315'},{x:26.6,y:225,samp:'CR11-309D_135-136.5'},{x:0.05,y:190,samp:'CR11-313D_42-43.5'},{x:48.8,y:180,samp:'CR11-313D_456-457.5'},{x:9.7,y:208,samp:'CR11-318D_73-74.5'},{x:0.6,y:13,samp:'CR11-323D_57-58.5'},{x:12.5,y:174,samp:'CR11-324D_181-182.5'},{x:0.05,y:153,samp:'CR11-324D_244-245.5'},{x:70.3,y:128,samp:'CR11-326D_369.5-371'},{x:4.4,y:181,samp:'CR11-328D_163.5-165'},{x:0.05,y:121,samp:'CR12-340D_476-477.5'},{x:26.6,y:149,samp:'CR12-341D_133.5-135'},{x:5.3,y:194,samp:'CR12-341D_147-148.5'},{x:195,y:73,samp:'CR12-342D_609-610.5'},{x:0.05,y:226,samp:'CR12-342D_66-67.5'},{x:37.8,y:208,samp:'CR12-345D_489-490.5'},{x:50,y:150,samp:'CR12-345D_594-595.5'},{x:37.5,y:239,samp:'CR12-346D_100.5-102'},{x:0.05,y:219,samp:'CR12-346D_21-22.5'},{x:40.6,y:259,samp:'CR12-346D_312-313.5'},{x:22.2,y:208,samp:'CR12-347D_157.5-159'},{x:0.05,y:478,samp:'CR12-348D_11-12.5'},{x:30.9,y:294,samp:'CR12-348D_156.5-158'},{x:42.5,y:238,samp:'CR12-349D_438-439.5'},{x:5.6,y:210,samp:'CR12-355D_529.5-531'},{x:28.1,y:221,samp:'CR12-355D_618-619.5'},{x:72.5,y:108,samp:'CR12-357D_427.5-429'},{x:35,y:258,samp:'CR12-366D_213-214.5'},{x:0.05,y:208,samp:'CR12-369D_36.5-38'},{x:10.3,y:163,samp:'CR12-372D_320-321.5'},{x:2.5,y:195,samp:'CR12-372D_47-48.5'},{x:22.8,y:175,samp:'CR12-374D_109.5-111'},{x:29.1,y:219,samp:'CR12-374D_174-175.5'},{x:42.5,y:203,samp:'CR12-374DB_372-373.5'},{x:30,y:175,samp:'CR12-375D_253.5-255'},{x:63.8,y:150,samp:'CR12-375D_304.5-306'},{x:18.8,y:165,samp:'CR13-377D_374-375.5'},{x:4.7,y:189,samp:'CR13-381D_55.5-57'},{x:72.2,y:163,samp:'CR13-386D_235.5-237'},{x:29.1,y:203,samp:'CR13-390D_159.5-161'},{x:12.2,y:204,samp:'CR13-393D_462-463.5'},{x:22.2,y:173,samp:'CR13-393D_481.5-483'},{x:23.8,y:179,samp:'CR13-394D_617-618.5'},{x:50.6,y:266,samp:'CR13-399D_189.5-191'},{x:7.8,y:245,samp:'CR13-409D_160.5-162'},{x:26.3,y:193,samp:'CR13-416D_506-507.5'},{x:42.5,y:176,samp:'CR13-422D_511.5-513'},{x:23.8,y:221,samp:'CR13-428D_510-511.5'},{x:88.8,y:259,samp:'CR13-432D_195.5-197'},{x:28.8,y:245,samp:'CR13-432D_236-237.5'},{x:7.2,y:158,samp:'CR13-433D_155-156.5'},{x:18.4,y:169,samp:'CR13-433D_228.5-230'},{x:43.8,y:229,samp:'CR13-433DB_303.5-305'},{x:1.9,y:159,samp:'CR13-433DB_488-489.5'},{x:27.2,y:233,samp:'CR13-435D_349.5-351'},{x:37.2,y:203,samp:'CR13-435D_429-430.5'},{x:26.6,y:223,samp:'CR13-438D_331.5-333'},{x:65.3,y:161,samp:'CR13-438D_573-574.5'},{x:365.9,y:79,samp:'CR13-440D_370.5-372'},{x:315.6,y:56,samp:'CR13-440D_382.5-384'},{x:11.9,y:183,samp:'CR13-444D_160.5-162'},{x:29.1,y:213,samp:'CR13-444D_202.5-204'},{x:2.5,y:214,samp:'CR13-447D_127.5-129'},{x:7.8,y:200,samp:'CR13-449D_272-273.5'},{x:17.2,y:266,samp:'CR13-449D_537.5-539'}]
},
{name: 'group5',
data: [{x:238.4,y:80,samp:'CR11-197D_418.5-420'},{x:0.9,y:12,samp:'CR11-226D_148.5-150'},{x:30.3,y:220,samp:'CR11-260D_121.5-123'},{x:45,y:309,samp:'CR11-260D_132-133.5'},{x:42.8,y:238,samp:'CR11-260D_183-184.5'},{x:6.3,y:499,samp:'CR11-282D_5-8'},{x:28.1,y:136,samp:'CR12-340D_279.5-281'},{x:0.05,y:134,samp:'CR12-343D_309-310.5'},{x:221.6,y:175,samp:'CR12-343D_316.5-318'},{x:24.4,y:203,samp:'CR12-347D_351-352.5'},{x:43.8,y:55,samp:'CR12-357D_543-544.5'},{x:29.7,y:259,samp:'CR13-389D_446.5-448'},{x:0.05,y:150,samp:'CR13-391D_116.5-118'},{x:0.05,y:208,samp:'CR13-391DB_115-116.5'},{x:40.6,y:249,samp:'CR13-394D_114.5-116'},{x:34.7,y:229,samp:'CR13-396D_247.5-249'},{x:23.1,y:186,samp:'CR13-414D_196.5-198'},{x:47.2,y:239,samp:'CR13-416D_392-393.5'},{x:81.6,y:54,samp:'CR13-428D_372-373.5'},{x:1.9,y:139,samp:'CR13-429D_583.5-585'},{x:18.4,y:235,samp:'CR13-432D_489.5-491'},{x:47.8,y:166,samp:'CR13-448D_230-231.5'},{x:14.4,y:201,samp:'CR13-451D_332-333.5'}]
},
{name: 'group6',
data: [{x:0.05,y:179,samp:'CR11-260D_112.5-114'},{x:0.05,y:585,samp:'CR11-267D_840.5-842'},{x:0.05,y:608,samp:'CR11-267D_852.5-854'},{x:68.4,y:560,samp:'CR11-300D_759.5-761'},{x:0.05,y:793,samp:'CR11-324D_917.5-919'},{x:39.1,y:525,samp:'CR12-346D_792-793.5'},{x:303.4,y:475,samp:'CR12-349D_865.5-867'},{x:135.9,y:550,samp:'CR12-352D_972-973.5'},{x:80.9,y:265,samp:'CR12-354D_1034-1035.5'}]
},
{name: 'group7',
data: [{x:3.4,y:299,samp:'CR11-294D_0-2'}]
},
{type: 'line',
  name: '3:1 Line',
  data: [[0, 0], [1000, 3000]],
  marker: {
  enabled: false
},
states: {
 hover: {
   lineWidth: 0 
   }
 },
 enableMouseTracking: false  
}],
exporting: {
   sourceWidth: 800,
   sourceHeight: 400,
   chartOptions: {
       subtitle: null
   }
}
});


$('#container2').highcharts({
chart: {
data: {
       table: eval(document.getElementById('report'))
  },
type: 'scatter',
zoomType: 'xy',
plotBorderColor: 'black',
plotBorderWidth: 1
},
   tooltip: {
   formatter: function() {
   return this.series.name + '<br><b>X: </b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, '1',',') +'<b>  Y:    </b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, '1',',') +'<br><span style="color: ' + this.series.color + '; font-weight:bold;">' + this.point.samp +'</span>';
},
series: [{
            name: 'new Series',  //this is the new series I want to populate the other charts
            data: (function() {table:
                data.push(document.getElementById('report'))
                return data;
            })
}]
}

});

});  
</script>
<body>

<table width="1200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><div id="container1" style="height: 400px; min-width: 530px"></div></td>
<td> <table id="report"></table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="container2" style="height: 400px; min-width: 530px"></div></td>
<td><div id="container3" style="height: 400px; min-width: 530px"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure I'm taking the right approach.  The end result will be the other 8 charts will be "dynamic" with respect to this other series (static data) that will be different X,Y pairs for each sample. So as I click on chart1, the other points appear in the other charts based on the sample ID.

my data is as follows:
    SampID    Data1    Data2    Data3     Data4     Data5     Data6    Data7, etc

Each of the 9 charts is a combination of these data but they all refer to the sampID.  So chart 1 is Data1 vs Data2, chart 2 might be Data2 vs Data6 but they all refer back to the sampID as these data are in rows.

The real challenge is trying to link the sampID of the selected samples in chart 1 with the sampIDs of the same name in Charts 2-9.

Any advice on this?

Comment: Honestly it is not clear for me, so you have list of charts and needs to highligh any if you click on it or something different?

Comment: I have 9 charts on a page. I want to use the first chart to highlight points.  These highlighted points will be used to highlight the "same" points on the other charts by referring to the sample ID name.  Here is what I'm working on.     http://jsfiddle.net/q2XKF/2/  I am testing one chart at a time right now. But I don't think the data is formatted properly for scatter.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure of table is incorrect, it should have `<thead>` element. Fixed example http://jsfiddle.net/q2XKF/5/